# Big Muff V7 Russian design problems?

Tags: eaglecad, analysis

I am trying to build this version of the Big Muff V7 on Eagle but can't seem to understand the schematic quite well. As you can seen on the image , there are couple 3 switches, sw 1a , sw 1b, and sw 1c , i can't understand how to connect those to the pedal switch , a.k.a Leg Switch .. My question is does anyone know how should i connect that switch to the rest of the schematic as i am quite confused ? Also does anyone have the Eagle footprint of those TRS female jack connectors ? [image] [image]

Comment: Is that just 3 contacts on the main button? To disconnect power and provide a bypass path when your not using the unit? Like a DT3P switch?

Comment: Also, any reason your making the Soviet USSR version?

Comment: The footswitch is a 3PDT switch, it has 3 separate double throw switches in the same switch body. [This page](https://www.coda-effects.com/2015/03/3pdt-and-true-bypass-wiring.html) has a good description of how to wire to it.

Comment: Sw1C is almost certainly drawn incorrectly on that diagram, also the track marked 'ground' is nothing of the sort, being in fact the bypass path.

Comment: @SteveG Thank you so much for the link for the explanation on the switch, it was very helpful .